# for loop in fancybox given syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

```
function  imgshow(val2){
    var arrayVal2 = val2.split(',');
    $.fancybox([
    for (i=0; i<arrayVal2.length; i++){
        'uploads/'+arrayVal2[i],
        //'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
        {
            'href'  : 'uploads/'+arrayVal2[i],
            'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
        }
    }   
    ], {
        'padding'           : 0,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'image',
        'changeFade'        : 0
    });
}
```

can i give for loop there. there is syntax error where i place for loop
i have images name in database. explode tham and store in a array. and call a for loop to show all images,
but given syntax error

please Guide me

Comment: should't you declare the var `arrayVal2` as an array before split it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid javascript

```
[for (;;) {}]
```

But you could do this

```
[
(function() {
var val = [];
for (i=0; i<arrayVal2.length; i++){
    val.push(['uploads/'+arrayVal2[i],
    //'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
    {
        'href'  : 'uploads/'+arrayVal2[i],
        'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
    }]);
}
return val;
)()
]
```

Though it's not pretty. I would recommend refactoring that section.